Navigating GNU screen in copy mode
In screen copy mode, shortcuts like "[ctrl a] a" still works to go to beginning of line, but "[ctrl e]" doesn't work anymore to go to end of line contents.
Instead I found [shft e] works to go to end of line physically (as in beyond last characters in the line, up to the end of screen display, including extra white spaces after the last character).
Is there any shortcut to navigate to end of line in copy mode?
The closest combination I could find is to use [shft e] to go to end of line, then [b] to go back one word before the last character, and finally [e] to reach actual last character of line.

I'm confused. Are you asking about "$", which goes to the end of line in copy mode?

OMG yes, thanks a lot. In hindsight "$" it makes so much sense but I couldn't find any info on shortcuts in copy mode.
